# Key word showing in \cite using BibTex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am having trouble getting bibtex to cite properly.

I am fairly new to LaTeX so please forgive me for any ignorance.

I am using Texmaker to utilise LaTeX.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

hello \cite{AAA}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibliography code

```
@book{AAA,
title = {apples and oranges},
author = {Fruit Shop},
year = {2000},
publisher={fruit}
```

Interestingly, the $\addbibresource$ is marked in bold blue font? Why is this?

The output is

[image: Output]

I have tried running the document in the sequence:

quickbuild
 BibTeX
 quickbuild
 quickbuild

But this does not seem to help.

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should check in the texmaker preferences that “quickbuild” really means PDFLaTeX. There is a closing `}` missing in the code of your .bib file. The rendering of `\addbibresource` in bold and blue is the standard highlighting syntax of texmaker. Does texmaker give any errors? What does your .blg file say?

Comment: The default bibliography compiler with biblatex is `biber`, not `bibtex`. If you absolutely want the latter (not recommended: you will loose some functionalities), add the option  `[backend=bibtex]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are actually almost there. Expanding Bernard's comment, `biblatex`'s default is the `biber` backend, so you should run `latex` -> `biber` -> `latex`. This question may help you set up your TeXmaker to do so: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/105447.

Comment: You may want to read [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864). [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) explains why you need to run BibTeX or Biber. Since you are using `biblatex`, you should be running Biber, but the explanations are roughly the same. You can find out how to make your editor run Biber in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Any news here? Could you get things going?